# How to solve $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{y^{m}}{(1+y/p)^{2m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{y^{m}}{(1+y/p)^{2m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y$$

where $m$ and $p$ are constant. I tried to solve it using LIATE rule but getting stuck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: Tried with partial fraction but not getting completely....can you elaborate it further....

Comment: Idk lol, maybe try substitution $u = (1 + y/p)$?

Comment: If $m$ is arbitrary (s.t. the integral converges), $y = x u$ gives [Euler's integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric#Integral_formulas) of the hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If $m$ is a non-negativeinteger, then by writing

\begin{align*}
\frac{y^m}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2}}
&= \frac{p^m (1 + (y/p) - 1)^m}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2}} \\
&= p^m \sum_{k=0}^{m} (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} \frac{1}{(1 + y/p)^{m+k+2}},
\end{align*}

we get

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{y^m}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y
&= p^{m+1} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{m+k+1} \binom{m}{k} \frac{1}{(1 + y/p)^{m+k+1}}.
\end{align*}

**2.** Alternatively, apply the integration by part $m$ times:

\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{y^m}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= -\frac{p}{2m+1} \frac{y^m}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+1}} + \frac{pm}{2m+1} \int \frac{y^{m-1}}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+1}} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&\hspace{4em}\vdots \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} p^k  \frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k-1} (m+1-j)}{\prod_{j=1}^{k} (2m+2-j)} \frac{y^{m+1-k}}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2-k}} \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} p^k  \frac{m!/(m-k+1)!}{(2m+1)!/(2m-k+1)!} \frac{y^{m+1-k}}{(1 + y/p)^{2m+2-k}}
\end{align*}

**3.** Yet another way is to write $q = -1/p$, and then starting from

$$ \int \frac{1}{(1 - qy)^{m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{m+1} \frac{1}{q(1 - qy)^{m+1}}, $$

apply the $m$-fold differentiate with respect to $q$ to both sides:

\begin{align*}
\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+1)!} \int \frac{y^m}{(1 - qy)^{2m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y
&= \frac{\partial^m}{\partial q^m} \int \frac{1}{(1 - qy)^{m+2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{m+1} \frac{\partial^m}{\partial q^m} \left( \frac{1}{q(1 - qy)^{m+1}} \right)
\end{align*}

The last line is not hard to compute using the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule).

---

In case $m$ is no longer an integer, I suspect that we will need special functions such as incomplete beta function.

Comment: By Chebyshev's theorem, assuming $m \in \mathbb Q$, the integral is elementary iff $2 m \in \mathbb Z$. If $m$ is a half-integer, $u = \sqrt y$ gives an integral of a rational function.

Comment: I put this integration in mathematica and answer is coming interms of Gauss Hypergeometric function. But i am not getting how it is coming ?

Comment: Ok.....@Sangchul lee.....

Comment: @charu, To be honest, I don't have an answer for that. I am not familiar with hypergeometric functions, and most of all, I am not sure if that is a better way of writing down an answer instead of just hiding the details into some 'less transparent' function.

Comment: Ok.....@Sangchul lee.....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\frac 1 {\left(1+\frac{y}{p}\right)^{2 (m+1)}}=\sum_{n=1} \binom{-2 (m+1)}{n}\left(\frac{y}{p}\right)^n$$